# How to prove: A quotient map $f:X→Y$ is open if and only if for every open subset $U⊆X$ the set $f ^{−1} (f(U)) $ is open in $X $

Tags: general-topology

How to prove the claim:
A quotient map $f:X→Y$ is open if and only if for every open subset $U⊆X$ 
the set $f ^{−1} (f(U)) $ is open in $X $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: By definition $f$ is open if and only if $f[U]$ is open in $Y$ for each open $U\subseteq X$. Now use the definition of the quotient topology: when is a subset of $Y$ open in the quotient topology?

Comment: @user34669: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If the map is open the clearly by definition, if $U$ is open, $f(U)$ is open, and so by continuity $f^{-1}(f(U))$ is open.

The other direction follows directly from the definition of quotient map, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map